# continuously differentiable implies Lipchitz on a compact in R^n?

Tags: real-analysis

Every function defined in a compact K\subseteq R^n that is continuously differentiable is Lipchitz on that compact?

Comment: Maybe yes, maybe no. Certainly yes for ""nice" $K$, but assuming just that $K$ is compact it depends: If $f:K\to\Bbb R$ what definition of "$f$ is continuously differentiable" do you have in mind?

Comment: @Topology Say $K=\{0,1\}\subset\Bbb R$ and $:K\to\Bbb R$ is defined by $f(x)=x$. I can imagine various definitions of "$f$ is continuously differentiiable" here, but this $f$ satisfies all of them. But you certainly cannot apply MVT.

Comment: The definition is:  f  is continuously differentiable if the derivative f′(x) exists and is itself a continuous function.

Comment: Right. The problem is what is the derivative? At an isolated point of $K$, for example...

Comment: @user426598 I see that you are completely unaware of problems occurring when one tries to define a $C^m$ function on an arbitrary closed $K\subset\mathbb{R}^n$: [Whitney extension theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitney_extension_theorem)

Comment: Say $K=\{0,1\}$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. What does the notation $f'(0)$ _mean_?

Comment: Is $f$ defined only on $K$ or on a neighborhood of $K?$ Please state the problem clearly and completely.

Comment: f is defined in K: f:K\rightarrow R

Comment: See the Answer I just posted for a detailed explanation of why the question still needs to be clarified....

Answer (score 1):

The question really can't be answered until we clarify what it means for $f:K\to\Bbb R$ to be continuously differentiable. All the OP has said about this is that $f'$ exists and is continuous on $K$. That really makes no sense for an arbitrary compact $K$, because it's not clear what $f'(x)$ means.

For example, if you look carefully at the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition you see that if $x$ is an isolated point of $K\subset\Bbb R$ then for *any* function $f:K\to\Bbb R$ the statements $$\lim_{K\ni y\to  x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=0$$ and $$\lim_{K\ni y\to  x}\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=1$$ are *both* correct.

So we really do need to clarify that definition. Having failed to convince thhe OP of this, I'm going to show that the answer to the question depends on which of various reasonable version of the definition we choose.

**Note** that I'm going to assume $K$ is a compact subset of $\Bbb R$ for simplicity.

First, regarding comments that seem to suggest the question is trivial, what's trivial is this:

> > **Triviality.** If $f\in C^1(\Bbb R)$ and $K\subset\Bbb R$ is compact then $f$ is Lipschitz on $K$.

Proof: Say $K\subset[-A,A]$. Choose $c<\infty$ so that $|f'(t)|\le c$ for every $t\in [-A,A]$. The Mean Value Theorem shows that $||f(x)-f(y)|\le c|x-y|$ for all $x,y\in K$.

Of course the Triviality really does not answer the question, because we're given only that $f:K\to\Bbb R$.

Here are two plausible definitions for "$f$ is continuously differentiable", given $f:K\to\Bbb R$.

> > **Def 1.** There exists an open set $O$ with $K\subset O$ and a function $g\in C^1(O)$ such that $g|_K=f$.
> >
> > **Def 2.** $f$ is continuous on $K$, differenntiable in the interior $K^o$, and $f'$ extends to a continuous function on $K$.

Of course Def 2 seems most likely to be interesting/useful if $K=\overline{K^o}$, but it does at least make sense for arbitrary $K$ (if we agree that it's vacuously satisfied when $K^o=\emptyset$).

> > > **True Fact.** If $K\subset\Bbb R$ is compact and $f:K\to\Bbb R$ is continuously differentiable in the sense of Def 1 then $f$ is Lipschitz.

Proof (or hint, depending on the reader) More or less the proof of the Triviality shows that for every $x\in K$ there exists an open intervall $I$ with $x\in I$ such that $f$ is Lipschitz on $K\cap I$. Cover $K$ by finitely many such intervals.

> > **Example.** There exists a compact $K\subset\Bbb R$, with $K=\overline{K^o}$, and $f:K\to\Bbb R$ such that $f$ is continuously differentiable in the sense of Def 2 but not Lipschitz.

Say $(I_n)$ is a sequence of disjoint compact intervals with $I_n\to0$ in the obvious sense. Let $$K=\{0\}\cup\bigcup_n I_n.$$Let $(c_n)$ be a sequence of reals with $c_n\to0$, and define $f:K\to\Bbb R$ by $$f(x)=
\begin{cases}0,&(x=0),
\\c_n,&(x\in I_n).\end{cases}$$

Then $f$ is continuous since $c_n\to0$, and $f$ satisfies Def 2 because $f'(t)=0$ for all $t\in K^o$. But we can certainly choose $(I_n)$ and $(c_n)$ so that $f$ is not Lipschitz.

To be slightly more explicit, first choose a strictly decreasing sequence $(c_n)$ tending to $0$. Now say $I_n=[a_n,b_n]$ with $b_{n+1}<a_n$. Choose $a_n\to0$ and $b_n\to0$ in such a way that $$\frac{c_n-c_{n+1}}{a_n-b_{n+1}}\to\infty.$$

Answer (score 0):

If a function is differentiable on $K$ (in the sense that the derivitive exists at every point in $K$), then it is Lipchitz iff its derivative is bounded on $K$. Would you be able to show this?

Comment: If $K$ is an arbitrary compact set in $\Bbb R^n$ what does it mean to say it's differentiable? (Say $K=\{0,1\}$, $f(0)=0$ and $f(1)=1$. What is $f'(0)$?)

Comment: Actually nobody can prove this. Of course there's the problem of exactly what we mean by "differentiable on $K$". Let's say $f$ is differentiable on $K$ if $f$ extends to a differentiiable function on some neighborhood of $K$; that seems like the strongest of various possible definitions. In fact there exist a differentiable function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and a compact set $K$ such that $f$ is Lipschitz on $K$ but $f'$ is unbounded on $K$.

Comment: I was dodging the issue that the derivative becomes difficult to define on an arbitrary compact set; The question seemed to start with the premise that the derivative exists on all of $K$. For most definitions I'm aware of, the derivative of a function at an isolated point is not well-defined. In that case, for a problematic $K$ like $\{0,1\}$, the statement is true because there are no continuously differentiable functions.